# Unable to set focus on ToolStrip button

Tags: vb.net, select, button, focus, toolstrip

I have tried to research this all morning and found no solution that worked for me.

I have a `ToolStrip`, with several `buttons` on it.  I am unable to get figure out how to select any of the buttons when using `tab`.  I did find that it would systematically select the `toolstrip` but showed no visual indication of that.  I only found this out by hitting the `left arrow key` each time I hit tab.

So my question is, how can I get one button on the `toolstrip(Button1)` to be selected *(so that when I would hit enter, it would automatically use the button)* by hitting the tab button.

I have turned the `TabStop = True` and the `TabStop` on the main UC is also set to True.  I have assigned the `ToolStrip` a final Index number also.  But still nothing gets highlight, but it's focused.  I want the `Button1` to be focused when I focus the `ToolStrip`.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your response was blank on my page.

Answer (score 2):

```
ToolStrip.Focus()

Button.Select()
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant set focus to any button in toolStrip except first Button or any element.
So dont try it.
Its Waste of time...I already tried..that.